# React-Redux + Redux-Thunk on functional component. Update UI after data is fetched from API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a functional component that fetches data from an api using redux.

```
const useFetching = (someFetchActionCreator) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(someFetchActionCreator());
    }, [])
}
```

The component:

```
export function Trips(props) {
    const trips = useSelector(state => state.trips);
    useFetching(fetchTrips)
...
...
}
```

The thunk:

```
export const fetchTrips = () => (dispatch) =>
    axios.get("/api/v1/trips")
        .then(response => dispatch(addTrips(response.data)))

export const addTrips = trips => ({
    type: ADD_TRIPS,
    payload: trips
})
```

The reducer:

```
function tripsReducer(state = INITIAL_STATE, action) {
    console.log(action)
    if (action.type === ADD_TRIPS) {
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            trips: state.trips.concat(action.payload)
        });
    }
    return state
}
```

My reducer is called. How can I update the UI after the fetched data have been dispatched? My render is not called again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**1st option: Using hooks**

You are actually using `React` and `react-redux` hooks. Make sure you use the object `trips` later in your component. Here is a sample using your code:

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchTrips } from '../tripsActions';

const useFetching = (someFetchActionCreator) => {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(someFetchActionCreator());
    }, []);
}

export function Trips(props) {
    const trips = useSelector(state => state.trips);
    useFetching(fetchTrips);

    return (
        <div>
            <p>Total trips: {trips.length}</p>
        </div>
    );
}
```

**2nd option: Using connect**

This was the way to connect to the Redux store state before they introduced the hooks.

As you are using **react-redux** this can be easily done by using the `connect()` function. You should also provide a `mapStateToProps()` function to select the part of the data from the store that your component needs and a `mapDispatchToProps()` function to have access to the actions to be dispatched.

This is how your `Trips` component would look like with this approach:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { fetchTrips } from '../tripsActions';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
    return {
        // will be available as props.trips
        trips: state.trips
    }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
    return {
        // will be available as props.fetch()
        fetch: () => dispatch(fetchTrips)
    }
}

const function Trips(props) {
    this.props.fetch();
    // some other code. Example:
    return (
        <div>
            <p>Total trips: {this.props.trips.length}</p>
        </div>
    );
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Trips);
```

`mapStateToProps()` receives the Redux store state and returns an object whose fields will be available as props in your component. As you already use `props.trips` I simply mapped that field to the updated value of the Redux state's `trips` field.

The call to `connect()` with your component gives you a *connected* component. And that latter should be exported rather than the original component. It will not create another component so you will continue to use the `Trips` component normally.

Now your component will be re-rendered as its props are being updated.

You can have a look at the react-redux documentation to better understand the use of [`connect()`](https://react-redux.js.org/api/connect) and [`mapStateToProps()`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapstate) and [`mapDispatchToProps()`](https://react-redux.js.org/using-react-redux/connect-mapdispatch) functions.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it easily like that:

```
import React, { 
    useCallback, useEffect 
} from 'react';
import { 
    useSelector, useDispatch 
} from 'react-redux';
// ../ducks for example
import { fetchTrips } from '../ducks';

const function Trips(props) {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    useEffect(() => {
       fetchTripsHandler();
    }, []);

    const fetchTripsHandler = useCallback(
        () => dispatch(fetchTrips()),
        []
    );     

    const { trips } = useSelector(state => ({
        trips: state.trips
    }));

    // your other component code
}
```

With `useSelector` from `react-redux` you can not use `connect`, `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps`. 
After that, your component will be connected to the Store.

Here is more information about [react-redux hooks](https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks#useselector).